# Why the clock interrupt never works in the middle of process?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, interrupt, osdev

When jumpint from kernel(RING0) to process(RING1), the clock interrupt never happen however long i wait.
But in the middlel of kernel, I use `sti` and `hlt` to test clock interrupt then it does happen. **I wanna know the reason why the clock interrupt never work in the middle of the process.**
Thanks in advance.

This is my process code.

```c
#include "type.h"
#include "const.h"
#include "intVector.h"
#include "important.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "prototype.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "global.h"

void delay(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {}
        }
    }
}

PUBLIC void TestA() { //0x05:0x30d01
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        dispPos = 0;
        dispStr("A");
        dispInt(i++);
        dispStr(".");
        delay();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are interrupts enabled while the pocess is running?

Comment: The overall code is in https://github.com/Virux-66/ViruxOS

Comment: @user253751 Yes. When in the middle of process, the eflags is 0x1202.

Comment: Are you sure you `delay` function isn't optimized away? (I don't think so)

Comment: I have run it in bochs with single-step debugging.I go into the loop and it runs many times, which , i think probably, is enough for a wating a clock interrupt to happen.

Comment: 10000 loops on GHz CPU is about 0.00001 sec.  Maybe use `while(true)`

Comment: Just a guess, but I wouldn't really expect that bochs would step into an interrupt handler if one should occur while single-stepping.  That would make it totally impossible to focus on the main-line code.  You might instead need to set a breakpoint in the interrupt handler, or something like that.  There might be an exception made for `hlt`, however, since there is no other way for the program to proceed except by an interrupt.

Comment: So in other words, my guess is that the interrupt is happening, but bochs simply isn't showing it to you.  Alternatively, that bochs suspends interrupts while single-stepping.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @NateEldredge But in some other codes like mine, the interrupt handler works within single-step debugging process. And I couldn't find the decisive difference between these and mine. If the effective code is needed, i will distribute it in Github.

Comment: @stark I wrote ```while(1){};``` at the begging of the process code and set a breakpoint in clock handler. However, when i ran it in bochs, it jumped to 0xf000:fff0 from the infinite loop and clock interrupt didn't occur.

Comment: `0x1202` in eflags is interrupts disabled right? There appears to be a spurious `cli` at the end of your interrupt handling before you unmask the clock by sending the IMR OCW to the 8259 PIC also I think `ret` should be `iret`

Comment: @LewisKelsey Thanks for your response. 
The ninth bit in eflags is IF, so 0x1202 means it enables interrupt, right? And I'm not sure what "spurious ```cli``` mean. Could you please say more detailedly?
For the ```ret```, this instruction dosen't exit to interrupt. It returns to  ```cont``` or   ``` reEntry```  where there is a ```iret```.

Comment: Well that's the error I made I thought about the ninth bit as opposed to bit 9 so yes you are right. And, I see it now, you push cont to the stack. I just glanced and saw your IRQhandler being set in the IDT and thought that was the last level, which would have been strange since you wouldn't have restored eflags or the trap frame. The problem is more subtle than I thought

Comment: Please, read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting a snippet of code here.  Your code doesn't show any problem, because is uncompilable, lacks a lot of function definitions, and cannot be tested at all.  You also don't show any trace or how you have determined that the clock interrupt is not happening, so it is impossible to make even a simple comment.  Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you have concluded that the clock interrupt doesn't happen when you are running a process in user mode, but that's not true.  If that where the case, on systems that don't have a hardware timer to allow them to be *tickless*, there should be no way to regain the control for the kernel in case the process doesn't yield the cpu itself.   What is true is that it happens transparently to the user, and can end in a context switch, if there's a process more prioritary and it's time to recalculate priorities.

Of course you cannot inihibit interrupts when you are in user mode, so in my opinion, the only way for you to know that interrupts have occured requires to install some kind of user mode accesible counter for the clock interrupt, and check it at regular intervals, or check for hardware interrupt acknowledges in the bus with a digital signal analyzer.

The clock interupt is normally the shortest to execute and the highest priority one, so thinking that something is impeding it is actually very wierd (normally, this means that only the nmi would interrupt a clock tick, but this normally implies some severe hardware failure ---nmi historically has been associated to parity failures in core memory or to imminent loss of power)

Comment: I think he's expecting to see 'INT 0x20 happen!' in the middle of those integers printed by the process to the screen

Comment: Well, he can use a kernel debugger and put a breakpoint in the interrupt handler.... the stack trace will take him to the problem.... but I don't think he will be able to do such a thing.

Comment: As you say, he is trying to identify in the code where and when the interruption is fired, IMHO he has poor idea of what a hardware interrupt is.

Comment: `mov edi,[dispPos]` is in `dispStr` but `dispPos` seems to only be set to 0, that cant be good. I was expecting to see a VGA address. At least `@dispStr` has an `int 0x10`

Comment: @LewisKelsey, you'll never see a call to a hardware interrupt in the assembler code.... the interrupt is triggered by an interrupt line, and can occur at any point in between two instructions.  Anywhere where the code runs with that interrupt enabled.  The cpu interrupts the normal execution of code to save the state of the most important cpu registers and jumps to the interrupt handler.  No instruction is in the code interrupted for that.

Comment: A user process cannot execute the `int` assembly instruction if it doesn't have a valid address gate.

Comment: Should you be able to execute `int 0x10` from your code, you could start calling it repeatedly to make your clock go faster and accelerate time virtually.

Comment: oh I wasn't replying about hardware interrupts, I was talking about how he's displaying 'A1' 'A2' etc to the screen

Comment: Do you mean `int 0x10` calling to the pc BIOS?  Pfffffff. :(

Comment: I see now, It looks like hes mapped a `gs` segment descriptor to VGA legacy memory, which is strange, but no he's only using `int 0x10` in the bios version of `dispStr` called `@dispStr`. This is unrelated to the hardware interrupt problem, but it might be related, but I can't actually see the behaviour of the bug because he hasn't shown it

Comment: The first thing is that he doesn't explain what environment he is using.  If he is running in windows protected mode or linux, then the memory map is flat, and he cannot tweak the segment registers, as they have very little use.  But he seems to be thinking also in 16bit protected mode, and not in 32bit or 64bit protected mode, which is common today.  Even if he is programming the boot loader, the majority of boot loaders' first task is to switch to protected mode to be able to load the kernel.  But he gives no information at all, so he cannot be helped.

Comment: @LuisColorado Sorry for my not overall description. Here are some more details about my system. First this system is a microkernel which is running under 32 bit protect mode. And in the SourceCode/booter/Loader.asm, I have jumped to protect mode by ```jmp dowrd LABEL_SelectorFlatC:(MACRO_LOADER_BASE* 0x10+LABEL_CODE_PMSTART```. Within kernel (RING0), the code segment and data segment are both flat mode. Then I make the code into kernel code by ```jmp LABEL_SelectorFlatC:MACRO_KERNEL_RELOADING``` in the SourceCode/booter/Loader.asm.

Comment: After it transfers to kernel code, it actually jumps to /SourceCode/kernel/Kernel.asm. Then in Kernel.asm, I load tss, ldt(which has been initialized before) and  restore the first process' all registers. After that, I use ```iretd``` to jump to the first process whose code is in /SourceCode/kernel/processDemo.c.

Comment: What my bug is that no matter how long i wait, the clock interrupt just doesn't occur. I run the whole system in the bochs. For testing whether the configuration of 8259A and IDT are set correctly, in /SourceCode/kernel/Kernel.asm, i write ```sti``` and ```hlt``` at the end of the file but before ```iretd``` and run. After executing ```hlt``` with command *s* in bochs , the code jmups to clock handler which is in /SourceCode/lib/clockService.c. So the result prove that the configuration about 8259A and IDT and so on are correct.

Comment: But in the /SourceCode/kernel/processDemo i write ```while(1)``` to wait the clock interrupt to occur. But it never happen no matter long i wait. I'm not sure if you have understant my problem completely. If not, sincerely,please tell any information you need. And I will respond as soon as possible. Thanks very much for your response.@LuisColorado

Comment: You cannot just sit for a hardware interrupt to occur.  Even if you could halt the cpu (this is not possible in user mode) you will wait for any interrupt, but the result is your program continuing executing as if nothing had happened.

Comment: For sure it has occured, hadn't it, your system clock would be going slow, and your time is correct, right?  In linux you can `cat /proc/interrupts`, and you have counters there for all the interrupts that have been processed by the system.  Look there and see how the interrupt corresponding to the clock device increments regularly.

Comment: @Virux what behaviour are you expecting to see. Are you expecting to see INT 0x20 occured among A1 A2 etc that are being printed to the screen? Are you sure it's not a bug with that dispStr, i haven't looked into it

Comment: @LewisKelsey What i want to see is that the clock interrupt can occur in the middle of TextA (which in the /SourceCode/kernel/processDemo.c). But at first, i went into the into a while(1) loop, no matter how many times i execute by single-step in Bochs, the interrupt just dosen't occur. And I'm sure the configuration about 8259A, IDT or something like that and dispStr (i had tested) are OK. So I felt very confused. 
After that, i increased frequency by setting 8253, from 56HZ to 100HZ. Then I went into TextA again, it did occur.

Comment: @Virux yes but does that mean you want to see something like `A132634.happen` in the top corner of your screen mid execution of that loop, that's what i'd imagine, seeing as you keep setting the position to 0. Also, have you correctly handled the case in dispStr where the incrementation of dispPos is atomic and masks interrupts? (I don't know because you've deleted the repository). Also are you saying it does it now that the clock is a higher frequency

Comment: something that occurs 1000 times in a second and lasts only half a microsecond.... what do you want to see?  Tell me that you are  using some bus analyser or at least an oscilloscope...

Comment: @LewisKelsey Yes, I want to see something like A132634.happen in the top corner of my screen mid execution of that loop. But the the incrementation of dispPos is not atomic and marks interrupts. Since i set the clock in a higher frequency which is 100HZ, I could see the clock interrupt occur mid TextA, which is my initial problem. So, I know the reson why i can't see the clock int occur before is that the frequency of clock is too low. The reason you can't see the repository is i set it private. Thanks for your continuous response.

Comment: @LuisColorado I'm not able to use bus analyser and oscilloscope or something like that. Im a rooke in these things. I just got into assembly language not long ago.

Comment: @Virux, then you are not able to see a timer interrupt that cannot be slown down. Can you see a bullet emerging from the front side of a gun?  How do you know that it comes out when you press the trigger?  You have to use an indirect method.... but you cannot **see it**.

Comment: Had timer interrupts not occur, then the only way your user process yield the cpu is to do it with a system call... if you don't do, and the system is working... then something must be happening in there for the system continuing to work.  This is the timer interrupt!!!! Can you believe it or not.  But it happens.